# store audio mp3 files into database and then retrieve on button click android

Tags: android, sqlite, audio

I am new bee to android. I have some about 120 audio files, which I want to store in database and then on different button clicks the audio files will retrieve which I want to play. I don't know how to do this. I have searched several links but unable to find help. I have little knowledge of SQLite database, any help will be appreciated.

here is my code , I have now only one audio file saved in assets folder.
If this can help.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;





public class MyButtonsActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        Button c = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstop); 
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnplay); 
        c.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                if(mp.isPlaying())
                    {  

                        mp.stop();

                    } 

            }


        });



        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                try {

                    mp.reset();
                    AssetFileDescriptor afd;

                    afd = getAssets().openFd("audio/001s-ff.mp3");
                    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.start();
                } 
                catch (IllegalStateException e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        });


    }
}
```

One thing more , where should I save my 100+ audio files? In assets folder manually or in database? which way will be more light in size?

Comment: Please narrow down your question to one specific thing. And a tip: You probably don't want to store the files in the DB, it is probably much better to store file paths to the files.

Comment: Ok I got it. thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: my audio files are 281 mb in size . which is taking too much time to compile. any suggestions?